# Disable completed items in xcode 8

Tags: xcode

I am building a UIView with multiple items on top of each other. How can I disable interaction with the elements I have already placed and used constraints on in xcode 8 so that I can be working on the other elements on top of them and not mess things up. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `isUserInteractionEnabled`property on `UIView`:

```
let view = UIView()
view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```